# Why does $\ln x / \ln b = \log_b x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm doing some Java code.  As far as I can tell, Java only has functions that do natural log and base $10$ log.  I have a requirement to specify the base.  I've seen that doing $\ln x/ \ln b$ is the same as $\log_b x$.

I've done this and it seems to work. I'd like to better understand why though.

Comment: As an example: $\log_{100}(1\phantom,\!000\phantom,\!000)=3$; $\dfrac{\log(1\phantom,\!000\phantom,\!000)}{\log(100)}=\dfrac62=3$. (Using the base-10 logarithm here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $y = \log_b x$. This is the same as $x = b^y$.

If you take the natural logarithm on both sides you get $$\ln x = \ln b^y = y \ln b$$ so that $y = \dfrac{\ln x}{\ln b}$. That is,
$$ \log_b x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}.$$

Comment: Could you explain why \ln b^y = y \ln b$$.  I follow up until that part and after.

Comment: That is one of the laws of logarithms and can be proved in a similar way. If $z = y \ln b$ then $z/y = \ln b$ and $e^{z/y} = b$. Raise both sides to the $y$ power to get $e^z = b^y$ which is the same as $z = \ln b^y$.